# How do I stop tailing with less but don't break pipe

Tags: pipe, less-unix

Say I invoke

```
some-stream() { while true; do openssl rand -hex 8; done }
some-stream | less +F
```

And hit `Ctrl-C` then less will stop tailing, but if I hit `F` to resume tailing then no more output will be generated. Presumably because the pipe was broken. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I guess one way would be to use `mkfifo`, but suppose I only want to read from `some-stream` lazily. Then what?

Comment: Maybe you could build something with `screen`?

Comment: Doesn't seem like that works, sorry.